# EWS SyncFolderItems missing cancelled meetings

Tags: exchangewebservices

In Exchange 2010 we have set up a room resource for a meeting room. This room is configured to AutoAccept all meeting requests.
We have a database application that tries to keep track of the occupation of that room. This is done by calling Exchange Web Services API every 10 minutes and request SyncFolderItems for that room.
This all works fine for new appointments and for changes to the appointment. However when a appointment is canceled this is also auto-accepted and all traces of the appointment disappear. SyncFolderItems does *not* show the appointment anymore as isCancelled.
Our database application never gets to know the cancellation this way.

We already set RemoveOldMeetingMessages to False but that does seem to make a difference.
Configuration for the room:

```
[PS] C:\>get-calendarprocessing Testroom | fl
RunspaceId                          : d71d9a9a-59f9-48c5-9a73-f26e13a0586a
AutomateProcessing                  : AutoAccept
AllowConflicts                      : False
BookingWindowInDays                 : 180
MaximumDurationInMinutes            : 1440
AllowRecurringMeetings              : True
EnforceSchedulingHorizon            : True
ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours         : False
ConflictPercentageAllowed           : 0
MaximumConflictInstances            : 0
ForwardRequestsToDelegates          : True
DeleteAttachments                   : True
DeleteComments                      : True
RemovePrivateProperty               : True
DeleteSubject                       : False
AddOrganizerToSubject               : True
DeleteNonCalendarItems              : True
TentativePendingApproval            : True
EnableResponseDetails               : True
OrganizerInfo                       : True
ResourceDelegates                   : {}
RequestOutOfPolicy                  : {}
AllRequestOutOfPolicy               : False
BookInPolicy                        : {}
AllBookInPolicy                     : True
RequestInPolicy                     : {}
AllRequestInPolicy                  : False
AddAdditionalResponse               : False
AdditionalResponse                  :
RemoveOldMeetingMessages            : False
AddNewRequestsTentatively           : True
ProcessExternalMeetingMessages      : False
RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications : False
MailboxOwnerId                      : contoso.com/Users/Testroom
Identity                            : contoso.com/Users/Testroom
IsValid                             : True
```

What can I do to detect a canceled meeting on a room resource?